# Constant factor in centering inequality of sub-gaussian distributions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, normed-spaces

Subgaussian norm of a random variable $X$ is defined as:
$$
\|X\|_{\psi_2} = \inf\left\{t > 0: \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{X^2}{t^2}}\right] \leq 2\right\}.
$$
For $L_2$ norm of a random variable we can write $\|X - \mathbb{E}[X]\|_2 \leq \|X\|_2$ which is called centering inequality. It is easy to prove that a similar inequality holds for subgaussian random variables as well. Namely,
$$
\|X - \mathbb{E}[X]\|_{\psi_2} \leq C\|X\|_{\psi_2}
$$
for some $C \geq 1$ which does not depend on $X$. I would like to see if this inequality holds for $C = 1$?